# How to let two-way data-binding <select> work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, select, typescript, angular

**UPDATE**: I got answer on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8215#issuecomment-214067069). The bug will be fixed in Angular 2 beta 16.

This is a simple two-way data-binding for `<select>`.

[Live demo using plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcACo4TkRLoDNfHJrmj8?p=preview).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="product.partCode">
      <option *ngFor="#part of parts" [value]="part.code">{{part.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select [(ngModel)]="product.levelCode">
      <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.code">{{level.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{product|json}}
  `
})
export class App {
  product = { partCode: 'aa', levelCode: 'lv1' };
  parts = [
    { code: 'aa', name: 'AA' },
    { code: 'bb', name: 'BB' }
  ];

  levels = [
    { code: 'lv1', name: 'Level 1' },
    { code: 'lv2', name: 'Level 2' }
  ];
}
```

When you select a new option, `{{product|json}}` can show it changes. This works well in **Chrome**, **Safari**, and **Opera**.

However when I use **Firefox Developer Edition 47.0a2** and **Firefox Nightly 48.0a1**, `{{product|json}}` won't change. How can I let it work in Firefox too? Thanks

Or maybe it is a bug? Should I report to Angular 2 or Firefox?

Comment: If you want to report it, it's an Angular2 bug, not Firefox. Also you can use their form plunker in the report, so they can clear see the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the **select two-way data binding** is bugged on Firefox, I tried with an example from Angular2 docs :
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/forms/ts/plnkr.html and it has the same issue as yours.

Until the bug is fixed, you can replace with a more old fashion code, something like:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <select (change)="selectPart($event)">
      <option *ngFor="#part of parts" [value]="part.code">{{part.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select (change)="selectLevel($event)">  
      <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [value]="level.code">{{level.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{product|json}}
  `
})
export class App {
  product = { partCode: 'aa', levelCode: 'lv1' };
  parts = [
    { code: 'aa', name: 'AA' },
    { code: 'bb', name: 'BB' }
  ];

  levels = [
    { code: 'lv1', name: 'Level 1' },
    { code: 'lv2', name: 'Level 2' }
  ];

  selectPart($event) {
    this.product.partCode = $event.target.value; 
  }

  selectLevel($event) {
    this.product.levelCode = $event.target.value;
  }
}
```

Updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/4cHCyBrSI932LOKKcxEN?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, @tibs. I got answer on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8215#issuecomment-214067069). The bug will be fixed in Angular 2 beta 16.

Comment: Nice one, good to know !